# How update to latest Beta software of Mac OS X without having to update incrementally

Tags: mac-appstore, developer-program, macos, beta-seed-program

I'm right now on Beta 2 of Mac OS X 10.11 "El Capitan" (15A204h)

The Mac App Store wants me to update to Beta 3 [image: AppStore proposes to update to Beta3]

I know that the latest Beta is Beta 7 (15A263e)

[image: Current Beta information]

Redeeming the code for Beta 7 doesn't work.

[image: Error redeeming code]

It seems that this is the same code that got me Beta 1

Image from Purchases section of App Store:
[image]

And I cannot see in "Purchases" section of App Store Beta 7 available.

Is there a way to upgrade from Beta 2 (or any earlier version) to Beta 7 directly. Without having to upgrade 5 times?

Comment: Are you a developer or are you using the Public Beta? Because the devs get different betas than the public, so the developer beta is up to Beta 7, while the Public Beta is up to Beta 5.

Comment: @RedEagle2000 Yes. I'm on the Developer's betas. And I redeemed code from Developer Site (for Beta 1). But this doesn't matter.  I wonder if Apple push "incremental updates" so I cannot update directly to Beta 7

Answer (score 1):

You can't - Apple hasn't released a combo updater (yet) and we're at β7 build 15A263e.

You can duplicate this radar if you find it a waste of time.

- http://www.openradar.me/22307567 The title isn't strictly correct - all installers so far are incremental.

So, your best bet is to get decent connection to the network and `softwareupdate --download --all` and then `softwareupdate --install --all` (or just straight install which downloads then installs)

Comment: "You can duplicate this radar".  Do you mean just coping report from openradar.me  and file report on  official radar bugreport.apple.com  to get notice from Apple Engineers for the cause?

Comment: @PaulBrewczynski download quick radar and paste the url/ open radar number as a duplicate. That's the easiest way I know.

Answer (score 1):

Update incrementally to Beta 3. And you will get immediate update to 7th beta (So they've done combo update from 3 to 7 - nothing more is known)

This is what is shown in App Store on Beta 3.
[image: Update from 3'rd Beta to 7'th]

After update:

[image: Beta 7 About this Mac]

Comment: That is cool. 7 dropped just after I answered so I didn't know it was combo as I was on 6. Glad you were saved a few reboots :)